# Create datatable with editable row/column and observe changes in it

Tags: r, shiny, dt

The DT documentation displays the possibility of creating editable rows, columns, and cells. When I use editable cells, everything works perfectly. I easily observe changes and could use them for my purposes. The problem is that I can't observe the changes in edited rows or columns.
The question is how to find out the edited row number, column, and new value when using editable rows/columns? A simple example from DT (doesn`t work) from it is shown below.
P.S. My DT version is 0.19, maybe its important

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dt_output = function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
    12, h1(paste0('Table ', sub('.*?([0-9]+)$', '\\1', id), ': ', title)),
    hr(), DTOutput(id)
  ))
}
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Double-click to edit table cells',

    dt_output('server-side processing (editable = "row")', 'x6')
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    d6 = iris
    d6$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d6))

    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))

    # server-side processing
    output$x6 = render_dt(d6, 'row')
    
    # edit a row
    observeEvent(input$x6_cell_edit, {
      print("ping")
      d6 <<- editData(d6, input$x6_cell_edit, 'x6')
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Up to my knowledge, there is no `input$x6_cell_edit` but only `input$tableId_cell_info` See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html for available objects. `tableId_cell_info` is just a JavaScript event...

Comment: I see. They use it here: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/.

Comment: @danlooo Yes, I took the example from  yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit. So It should work, but no...

Comment: Your example does work for me. I have DT version 0.20, shiny 1.7.1, R 4.1.1

Comment: @LevonIpdjian Could I ask you to send me a print for input$x6_cell_edit? I try to understand how it works and what is wrong with my R.

Comment: Here it is : 

  row col                value
1   1   0                    1
2   1   1                  5.1
3   1   2                    5
4   1   3                  1.4
5   1   4                  0.2
6   1   5               setosa
7   1   6 2022-02-17T12:51:35Z
The display is very unreadable in comments, so I post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a shiny app showing a editable data table and another table of edits:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    h1("Data"),
    DTOutput("table"),
    h1("Edits"),
    DTOutput("edits")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    edits <- reactiveVal(value = tibble(
      row = numeric(),
      col = numeric(),
      value = character()
    ))
    
    output$table <- renderDT(iris, editable = TRUE)
    output$edits <- renderDT(edits())
    
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
      edits() %>%
        add_row(input$table_cell_edit) %>%
        edits()
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this example shows editing cells. And as I said it works for me also. I need to observe the same editing, but with parameter editable = "column"

Comment: There is still the event `input$table_cell_clicked` giving you the row and column you are currently editing, even in `column` mode. However, the value is not changing accordingly here. I think this is not an official feature of DT shiny, because it's not documented comprehensively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `print(input$x6_cell_edit)`

```
>      row col                value
>     1   1   0                    1
>     2   1   1                  5.1
>     3   1   2                    5
>     4   1   3                  1.4
>     5   1   4                  0.2
>     6   1   5               setosa
>     7   1   6 2022-02-17T12:51:35Z
```

I edited the first observation, column "Sepal.width".